# Performance de pesquisa envolvendo múltiplos discos

Tags: sql-server, join

Supondo que uma *query* que utiliza `JOIN` entre duas ou mais tabelas, tal como:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo INNER JOIN bar ON foo.id = bar.id
```

Existe ganho de performance se os dados das tabelas estiverem em HD's diferentes *(devido a ter mais cabeçotes realizando leitura ao mesmo tempo, suponho)* ? Se houver, como faço para separar minhas tabelas em unidades de armazenamento diferentes?

E no caso de junção implícita/join "natural"? I.e.:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo, bar
WHERE foo.id = bar.id
```

Comment: Responder sua pergunta é algo que depende de conhecimento bem detalhado a respeito do funcionamento do SQL Server. Se fosse um banco opensource, muito provavelmente alguém já teria feito uma análise mais profunda. Posso afirmar, entretanto, que existe ganho ao separar as tabelas em discos diferentes. Alguns separam até mesmo os índices da tabela propriamente dita. O processo de separar as tabelas em discos diferentes é algo bem tranquilo de fazer no SQL Server. Fazemos isso em um sistema com banco de dados >350 GB. A tabela de auditoria está em um raid separado e só ela tem >200 GB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se feito da forma correta, haverá um ganho de performance (talvez mínimo dependendo da sua aplicação). A implementação de um banco de dados em vários HD's é um pouco complexa e talvez desnecessária para o tamanho do seu projeto.

**Tentando resumir:** Quando você realiza um `join` entre duas tabelas o SQL Server irá consultar muito mais além do que o conteúdo da tabela, por exemplo, os **índices** para tentar encontrar as informações necessárias. Se esses índices não estiverem implementados corretamente, você perderá uma performance considerável.

Formas mais simples para melhorar performance:

- Pôr arquivos de log/backup do banco de dados em outro disco rígido.
- Criar índices para suas principais consultas.
- Apagar registros não utilizados (aqueles do ano retrasado que estão lá apenas para prejudicar sua consulta), ou colocá-los em um outro banco de dados.

Se mesmo assim você está interessado em particionar:
http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/w/wiki/9650.partitioning.aspx

Algumas dicas de como melhorar a performance:
http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/w/wiki/10373.configuring-database-files-for-optimal-perfomance.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Como disse o Wédney, a melhora seria mínima. Na verdade, nem sei se haverá ganho de verdade, afinal não creio que o SQL Server consiga realizar a leitura das duas tabelas em paralelo ou de forma assíncrona para uma mesma query.

## Considerando o Plano de Execução

Antes de começar a ler o disco, os sistemas de bancos de dados como SQL Server primeiro calculam o plano de execução. O primeiro passo é verificar se existe algum índice com o qual ele possa determinar antecipadamente quais registros deverão ser lidos da tabela física.

Se o join for realizado apenas pelas chaves primárias em `foo` e `bar`, então certamente haverá índices. Ter bastante memória ajuda o SQL Server a manter os índices em memória e assim evitar leituras de índices do disco. Sendo assim, até este passo, nenhuma leitura seria necessária.

Com o plano de execução calculado, sabendo exatamente quais registros devem ser lidos do disco, o SQL Server iniciará então a leitura dos registros do disco. Se eles estão em discos separados, talvez não faça diferença, afinal ele provavelmente precisa esperar a leitura de uma tabela ou registro para então acessar a outra tabela.

Além disso, mesmo que as duas tabelas estejam em discos diferentes, nada garante que os movimentos da agulha do HD serão mais eficientes. Os dados de uma mesma tabela podem estar fragmentados em setores espalhados pelas trilhas do HD.

## Conclusão

Portanto, talvez seja muito mais eficiente simplesmente compactar o seu banco de dados, de forma a eliminar trechos não utilizados do arquivo, e então desfragmentar o HD,